# word wrap in HTML for RShiny while keeping MathJax

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, word-wrap

Suppose we have `longtext.Rmd` file that returns html to be displayed in RShiny using `withMathJax(includeHTML("www/longtext.html"))`

```
---
output: html_fragment
---

# **1. Heading**

long text looooooooooooooooongtext $\delta_{0}$

long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext $\delta_{0}$$\delta_{0}$

long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext

long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext 



long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext long text looooooooooooooooongtext
```

And the UI for Rshiny below:

```
tabPanel(title = "Panel 1",
         fluidRow(
           wellPanel(

             #attempt1: create x-scroll and does not wrap
             withMathJax(includeHTML("www/longtext.html"))

             #attempt2: wraps, but does not evaluate math equation
             withMathJax(tags$iframe(src = './longtext.html',
                                     width = '100%', height = '800px',
                                     frameborder = 0, scrolling = 'auto'
             ))

             #attempt3: create x-scroll and does not wrap
             column(12,
                    (div(style=
                           'width:100%;
                            height:800px;
                            overflow-y: scroll;
                            word-break: break-all;
                            overflow-wrap: break-word;
                            word-wrap: break-word;',
                         withMathJax(includeHTML("www/longtext.html"))
                    ))
             )
           )
         )
)
```

First attempt, simple `withMathJax(includeHTML())`, does not wrap the long text, i.e., last paragraph is a single line that overflows `wellPanel()`.

Second attempt, using `tags$iframe` fails to evaluate the MathJax.

Third attempt, using `div` within column, returns same outcome as the first attempt.

What would be the  proper way to display the longtext, in a way that it will be wrapped properly to account for the window size of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"white-space: normal;"

in the global setting